# Confirming the encoding of a file

Tags: linux, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I am outputting a file from SSIS in UTF-8 Encoding.
This file is passed to a third party for import into their system.
They are having a problem importing this file. Although they requested UTF-8 encoding, it seems they convert the encoding to ISO-8859-1.  They use this command to convert the files encoding:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 dweyr.inp
```

They are receiving this error

```
illegal input sequence at position 11
```

The piece of text causing the issue is:

```
ark O’Dwy
```

I think its the apostrophe, or whatever version of an apostrophe is used in this text.
The problem i face is that every text editor i try tells me the file is UTF-8 and renders it correctly.
The vendor is saying that this char is not UTF-8.

How can i confirm whom is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message by iconv is a bit misleading, but kind-of correct.

It doesn't tell you that the input isn't valid UTF-8, but that it cannot be converted to ISO-8859-1 in a lossless way. ISO-8859-1 does not have a way to encode the `’` character.

Verify that by executing this command:

```
echo "ark O’Dwy" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-7
```

This produces the output that looks like `"ark O+IBk-Dwy"`.

Here I'm outputting to UTF-7 (a very rarely used encoding that is useful for demonstration here, but little else).

In other words: the encoding is only "illegal" in the sense that it cannot be converted to ISO-8859-1, but it's a perfectly valid UTF-8 sequence.

If the third party claims to support UTF-8, then they may do so only very superficially. They *might* support any text that can be encoded in ISO-8859-1 as long as it's encoded in UTF-8 (which is an extremely low level of "UTF-8 support").